# Animating a Raphael circle

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael

I'm new to Raphael and trying to move a circle I created, either by animation or just by setting the new X and Y coordinates.

```
_raphael = Raphael(10, 10, 800, 600);    
var nodeCircle = _raphael.circle(100,100,30);
nodeCircle.animate({x:500, y:200}, 1000);
```

I can't figure out why this isn't working. I'm rendering in IE9 but also doesn't work in Firefox. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Thats because a circle uses cx and cy and not x,y..so this should work...

```
_raphael = Raphael(10, 10, 800, 600);    
var nodeCircle = _raphael.circle(100,100,30);

nodeCircle.animate({cx:500, cy:200}, 1000);
```

Comment: Woah, that's weird. Thanks! I read through the documentation and couldn't see that. Thanks! It's working now.